# Read FASTA file into hash

Tags: perl

I'm trying to read a [FASTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) file into a hash.

**Problem**

```
my $primer_seq_14bp = q(); // --> works
my $primer_seq_14bp; // --> error
```

```
Use of uninitialized value $primer_seq_14bp in hash element at ./script.pl line 24, <FWDPRIMER> line 1.
```

Why does this variable need to be declared as an empty string?

This is part of my first "on my own" script, so feedback on formatting, efficiency, etc. is welcome!

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my %primer_name_for;
my $primer_name;
my $primer_seq_14bp;

# Store fwd primer sequences in a sequence{name} hash.
open FWDPRIMER, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "error reading $ARGV[0]\n";
while (<FWDPRIMER>) {
    chomp;
    if ( /^(>.+)/ ) {
        $primer_name = $1;
    }
    else {
        $primer_seq = $_;
        $primer_seq_14bp = substr $primer_seq, 0, 14;
    }
    $primer_name_for{$primer_seq_14bp} = $primer_name;
}
close FWDPRIMER;
```

**Input**

Fasta file, which is formatted:

```
>Sequence_name
DNA_sequence
>Sequence_name
DNA_sequence
```

etc.

The entire file is in this format, so I thought I could use `$_` because if the line isn't a name it has to be a sequence.

**Goal**

A hash where `DNA_sequence` is the key for `Sequence_name`. The ultimate action is to search the hash with read sequences to get the biological name of the read (reads come with a default name).

**Example**

Input primer

```
>snp_fwd_primer
AAGCTCCTGCAGGTCATCTC
```

Input read

```
>read_name
AAGCTCCTGCAGGTCATCTCTAGTTGACACCTTTGCTGACAATTATTGTG
```

Desired output

Note that the first 20 bp of the read matches the primer sequence. The script cuts the read sequences to 14 bp because that is the length of my shortest primer sequence.

```
>snp_fwd_primer
AAGCTCCTGCAGGTCATCTCTAGTTGACACCTTTGCTGACAATTATTGTG
```

**Update**

I have a solution, however, the answers below are much better. I'm sharing it for other lost biologists (my solution is based on bioinformatics forums).

I changed the record delimiter `$/` to read the input primer fasta one entry at a time (I always convert multi-line fasta to single-line; for multi-fasta see @ikegami's answer). Then used regrex to separate the header from the sequence. The major downside is that I have to manually remove the very first `>` from the input primer fasta (learned that you can't close and reopen the same file in a perl script).

This did not apply to the input read fasta because I wanted only the sequence line, so I skipped any line that began with `>`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Usage: thisScript.pl fwdPrimers.fasta reads.fasta > reads_with_primer_names.fasta
# Fasta files need to be in single-line format.
# Before running, remove the first instance of '>' from the fwdPrimerFastaFile!
# Purpose: for reads that have marker forward primer sequences, rename the read with the marker name.

use strict; use warnings;

open PRIMERFILE, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "error reading $ARGV[0]\n";
$/ = '>';

# Store fwd primer sequences in a sequence{name} hash.
my %primer_name_for;

while (<PRIMERFILE>) {
    /(.+)\n(.+)\n/ and my $primer_name = $1 and my $primer_seq = $2;
    my $primer_seq_14bp = substr $primer_seq, 0, 14;
    $primer_name_for{$primer_seq_14bp} = $primer_name;
}
close PRIMERFILE;

# Store reads in a full_length_read{trimmed_read} hash. 
# Use trimmed read to search the fwd primer hash. 
# Combine primer name and full length read.
open READFILE, '<', $ARGV[1] or die "error reading $ARGV[1]\n";
$/ = "\n";

my %read_fullSeq_for;
my $read_seq;

while (<READFILE>) {
    chomp;
    if($_ =~ /^>/){ 
        next;
    }
    else {$read_seq = $_};
    my $read_seq_14bp = substr $read_seq, 0, 14;
    $read_fullSeq_for{$read_seq_14bp} = $read_seq;
    if (exists $primer_name_for{$read_seq_14bp} and $read_fullSeq_for{$read_seq_14bp}) {
        print ">$primer_name_for{$read_seq_14bp}\n$read_fullSeq_for{$read_seq_14bp}\n";
    }
}
close READFILE;

__END__
```

Comment: You are using `undef` as a hash key. That is what the warning means. That `undef` will be cast to the empty string. Not a very meaningful hash key. The solution is to not use the variable as a hash key when it is not defined.

Comment: In a sense, when you say it "works", it doesn't really work. You just don't get a warning about it not working.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The fundamental problem is that these variables are forward-delcared for no reason. Why not declare/scope them inline where they're used? Tighter scoping = fewer bugs, easier to understand code.

Comment: @ggorlen That is a problem, but it is not the fundamental problem. In fact it has nothing to do with the warning. But it could lead to hard to diagnose errors later on (e.g. saving a value from a previous line to the next line(s)).

Comment: I'd argue it is the fundamental problem. If you use `my $primer_seq_14bp = substr $primer_seq, 0, 14;` then you are forced to change the logic to be sensible. Scoping variables globally like this enables goofy control flow abuse that leads to all kinds of problems, of which OP's specific complaint is just one symptom. It's not clear what OP is trying to do in any case -- seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). @Kip showing the input file and expected output is nice so folks can offer a potentially better approach. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I tried `my $primer_seq = $_;` and `my $primer_seq_14bp = substr $primer_seq, 0, 14;` but got this error (abbrev) `Global symbol...requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare...at...line 21.`

Comment: @ggorlen He is trying to read a fasta file with a header followed by a sequence. It is not possible to use lexically scoped variables when reading line by line in this case.

Comment: Seems best to not reinvent the wheel for reading FASTA: https://metacpan.org/dist/TIGR/view/lib/TIGR/FASTA/Reader.pm. It's possible to avoid scoping using nested loops, the outer loop read keys and the inner loop reads values, leaving the outer loop back at the next key. Wikipedia seems to suggest that FASTA values can be multiline, so I'm still not sure what OP's actual specification is for the file based on the pseudocode, although there's more context now (thanks, OP!).

Comment: Thanks for the update.  That logic is fine but it fails on the very first line, since the hash key could not get initialized up to that point  (a hash key must always have a sensible value of course), as @ikegami already showed you.  One way out is to first process the first line, before the loop, by reading that one line from the file, and then enter the loop.  Or tweak your logic to account for that first line

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, that is what I want to do<br>Thank you for helping me--I've avoided posting a question because the comments can be harsh, but so far people have been super helpful.<br>Edited to remove my proposed solution in light of additional feedback.

Comment: No problem, you're doing fine and thanks for interacting with commenters and clarifying your question. Is `DNA_sequence` multiline or always a single line? An actual snippet of the file, say, half-dozen representative key-value pairs might help. Thanks.

Comment: @ikegami Ohh, because of your explanation I finally understand. I am not experienced enough to immediately grasp what ggorlen and TLP were telling me. I am going to redo this with everyone's advice and get back to you all (hopefully tomorrow).

Comment: There's also bioperl, which has a fasta reader (And many other related formats)

Comment: @Kip You should probably use a module designed to read fasta files. Such as maybe bioperl, but I have no experience of such.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Besides hashes, I also better understand lexical scope and if/else. I know about bioperl (and now know how much time it saves) but thought to try this from scratch to help me learn perl basics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say the first line matches `/^(>.+)/`. Then you end up doing

```perl
$primer_name_for{undef} = $primer_name;
```

because you never assigned anything to

```perl
$primer_seq_14bp
```

You should only be adding to the hash when you have a sequence.

```perl
my %primer_name_for;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^>(.*)/s) {
        $primer_name = $1;
    } else {
        my $primer_seq = $_;
        my $primer_seq_14bp = substr($primer_seq, 0, 14);
        $primer_name_for{$primer_seq_14bp} = $primer_name;
    }
}
```

One problem. The sequences can span multiple lines. To fix this, we'll just add to the hash when we encounter a heading or EOF.

```perl
my (%primer_name_for, $name, $seq);
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^>(.*)/s) {
        $primer_name_for{substr($seq, 0, 14)} = $name if defined($name);
        $name = $_;
        $seq = '';
    } else {
        $seq .= $_;
    }
}

$primer_name_for{substr($seq, 0, 14)} = $name if defined($name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please investigate following sample code for compliance with your problem.

My understanding that OP tries to build reverse lookup table for sequence name as hash value, based on partial DNA sequence as a hash key.

NOTE: it would be helpful for clarification of the problem to have some sample input data and desired output

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $length = 14;
my %sequence = do { local $/; <DATA> =~ />(.*?)\n([^>]*)/gs};

$sequence{$_} =~ s/\n//g for keys %sequence;

my %lookup_table = map { substr($sequence{$_},0,$length) => $_ } keys %sequence;

say Dumper(\%sequence);
say Dumper(\%lookup_table);

exit 0;

__DATA__
>SEQUENCE_1
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
LVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHK
IPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTL
MGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGLEKKTEDFAAEVAAQL
>SEQUENCE_2
SATVSEINSETDFVAKNDQFIALTKDTTAHIQSNSLQSVEELHSSTINGVKFEEYLKSQI
ATIGENLVVRRFATLKAGANGVVNGYIHTNGRVGVVIAAACDSAEVASKSRDLLRQICMH
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'SEQUENCE_2' => 'SATVSEINSETDFVAKNDQFIALTKDTTAHIQSNSLQSVEELHSSTINGVKFEEYLKSQIATIGENLVVRRFATLKAGANGVVNGYIHTNGRVGVVIAAACDSAEVASKSRDLLRQICMH',
          'SEQUENCE_1' => 'MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEGLVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHKIPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTLMGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGLEKKTEDFAAEVAAQL'
        };

$VAR1 = {
          'MTEITAAMVKELRE' => 'SEQUENCE_1',
          'SATVSEINSETDFV' => 'SEQUENCE_2'
        };
```